# Having problems using Invoke to execute a method

Tags: c#, invoke

I have a C# progranm that is using a Flash control to play a movie. The problem I'm having is when I try to send a message to Actionscript before the movie has completely loaded I receive an error. To resolve the problem I set a timer to wait 1 second before continuing. That in turn created a different problem because I'm now running on a different thread. To resolve that problem I've tried using Invoke in the timer event handler but it doesn't seem to actually invoke the method for some reason. I can see that 50% of the cpu is being used by the process but it never comes back from the Invoke statement. I have looked at a number of questions and I have tried 4 or 5 of different ways to use the Invoke and BegainInvoke methods. The design of my applications is that I have a main class that instantiates the form. The constructor of the form loads and starts to play the movie. The main class sets the timer and the tries to show the form, which is where the problem occurrs.

```
    public MyClass()
    {
        demoForm = new DemoForm();

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(engine);

        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Enabled = true;

        for (int i = 0; ; i++)
            counter++;
    }

    private void engine(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        timer.Enabled = false;

        if (demoForm.InvokeRequired)
        {
            demoForm.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(sendNextMessage));
        }
        else
        {
            sendNextMessage();
        }

    }

    private void sendNextMessage()
    {
        // It never gets here!!!
    }
```

Comment: I think you should be using `demoForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(sendNextMessage));` instead of `demoForm.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(sendNextMessage));`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried using both BeginInvoke and Invoke with the same result.

Comment: Yes, I have just tested this myself. Perhaps there is something in DemoForm's constructor that is blocking it from being created? So when the timer kicks in, it's constructor is still running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an infinite busy loop:

```
  for (int i = 0; ; i++)
        counter++;
```

The construction of your object will never complete, and you are probably blocking the GUI thread which will prevent any messages from being handled, including the `Invoke`.

You are probably seeing 50% CPU usage because you have a dual core processor. One of the cores is sitting in the busy loop repeatedly incrementing the counter. The other core is idle.

You say that you were using the loop to prevent the application from terminating, but this is not the correct way to do it. You should call `Application.Run` from the main method. Visual Studio adds this code automatically for you when you create a new Windows Forms project.

**Suggestion**

Create two forms. Put the Flash control in its own form and show that form first. When that form is closed, you can then open the second form to show the rest of your application.

Comment: No, when the timer elapses it will execute the event handler, which is the engine method. This all works until the statement demoForm.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(sendNextMessage)); It never comes back after that.

Comment: -1. While this certainly is an infinite loop, the problem is of completely different nature. The timer is running on a different thread, so I cannot see this as an answer to the question.

Comment: @NikolaMalešević: The timer posts events to the message queue. But the infinite loop will prevent any messages from being handled.

Comment: When I changed the statement counter++ to Applications.DoEvents() it worked. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @MarkByers Nope, just tested this, the timer fires up and `sendNextMessage()` is called every second.

Comment: @MarkBryers no I haven't. What I'm trying to do is to be able to load the Flash movie and have it playing before the form shows. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @MarkByers It appears you have mistaken timer's class. It is `System.Timers.Timer`, not `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: @MarkByers how would you suggest that I keep my app from terminating? Thanks.

Comment: @MarkByers I just saw your suggestion from eariler. That won't work for this app. The flash is interactive and it may display multiple messages that the user responds to. In fact there are actually 5 flash movies and 4 of them require the user to respond. Right now I have all 5 in different forms, but it's only the first one that I need to wait to load. The initial class is the driver. My thought was to make each form visable as they are needed.

Comment: @MarkByers Based on your reputation, you're surely more competent than me to be of help to this issue, but my opinion is that your solutions are based on false observations and conclusions, and therefore cannot be rendered into anything useful for OP's problem. I repeat, `sendNextMessage()` **is** being called regularly, and I do not believe that you will be able to help OP until you try and test this for yourself. I'm sorry I cannot be of any further help.